# Excel VBA: change date in cell when range in row is updated; laggy code

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a code to change a date in column T when any cells in, column C to R are changed.

The code works but it's making the workbook super laggy and slow. Is there a way to make this code efficient?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim WorkRng As Range, rrow As Long
    Dim Rng As Range
    Set WorkRng = Intersect(Range("B1:R300"), Target)
    If Not WorkRng Is Nothing Then
            For Each Rng In WorkRng
                rrow = Rng.Row
                If Not Rng.Value = "" Then
                    Cells(rrow, "T").Value = Now
                    Cells(rrow, "T").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy h:mm"
                Else
                    Cells(rrow, "T").ClearContents
                End If
            Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Might be worth disabling events using `Application.EnableEvents = False` and then resetting to `True` at the end.

Comment: It's not clear what this code is intended to do?  It either adds a timestamp or clears it depending on whether a cell within columns B:R has a value or not?  So clearing one cell would remove the timestamp added by a different cell change on the same row?

Comment: Hi, I tried .enableevents and it still lags quite a bit for a small code. I also thought .enableevents makes it slower.

Comment: Hi Tim, so if I change the value in B: R range, then the cell in T will have a "last updated" date & time, if I clear in that range, the cell would remove the timestamp in cell T. I hope that clears it up.

Comment: So it you add a value in B2 it puts a timestamp in T2, and then if you clear a value in C2 it clears the timestamp from T2?  Seems odd to me.

Comment: No, it only clears the timestamp if the entire range is empty.

Comment: `If Not Rng.Value = ""` only looks at a single cell though?  If B2 has a value and I clear C2, then `WorkRng` only contains C2, and the timestamp will get cleared.   If you want to test if the whole row is empty then use something like `If Application.CountA(Rng.EntireRow.Range("B1:R1")) = 0 Then`   Note the "B1:R1" there is *relative* to  `Rng.EntireRow`

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this if you want to clear the timestamp when a row has no data in columns B:R

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Const FLAG_COL As String = "T"
    
    Dim WorkRng As Range, c As Range, rw As Range, cT As Range
    
    Set WorkRng = Intersect(Me.Range("B1:R300"), Target)
    If Not WorkRng Is Nothing Then
        For Each c In WorkRng.Cells
            Set rw = c.EntireRow
            Set cT = rw.Columns(FLAG_COL) 'timestamp cell
            'any data in B:R on this row?
            If Application.CountA(rw.Range("B1:R1")) > 0 Then
                cT.Value = Now
                cT.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy h:mm"
            Else
                cT.ClearContents
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The timestamp is updated on each row change in the selected Range and is deleted if all cells in the row have no value.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Dim checkRange As Range, changedRange As Range, wrkRow As Range, rrow As Long
   Dim Rng As Range
   
   Err.Clear
   On Error GoTo Lerr
   Application.EnableEvents = False
   Set checkRange = Range("B1:R300")
   Set changedRange = Intersect(checkRange, Target)
   If Not changedRange Is Nothing Then
      For Each Rng In changedRange
         rrow = Rng.row
         If Rng.value = vbNullString Then
            Set wrkRow = Intersect(Rng.EntireRow, checkRange)
            If WorksheetFunction.CountA(wrkRow) = 0 Then
               Cells(rrow, "T").ClearContents
            Else
               GoTo LsetTimeStamp
            End If
         Else
LsetTimeStamp:
            Cells(rrow, "T").value = Now()
            Cells(rrow, "T").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy h:mm:ss"
         End If
      Next
   End If
Lerr:
   Application.EnableEvents = True
   If Err.Number <> 0 Then
      MsgBox ("Error> " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description)
   End If
   On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```